# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'CreatePortfolioController' is not registered

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-app is added in the html tag. I have added just a portion of html code.
I am trying to use the CreatePortfolioController but it seems to be undefined. I checked for typo errors too, but there seems to be none. I have no idea why it is not working. Can you please help me debug?

App.js

```
var app = angular.module("UiApp", ["ServiceApp"]);

app.service('sharedProperties', function () {
    var idValue = 'test string value';

    return {
        getId: function () {
            return idValue;
        },
        setId: function (value) {
            idValue = value;
        }
    }
});

app.controller("PortFolioController", function ($scope, GetPortfolios, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.Portfolios = GetPortfolios.query({ pmid: 2 });
    console.log($scope.Portfolios);
    $scope.addOrder = function (id) {
        sharedProperties.setId(id)
    };
});

app.controller("CreatePortfolioController", function ($scope, CreatePortfolio) {
    $scope.create = function (data) {
        CreatePortfolio.save(data);
    };
});

app.controller("OrderController", function ($scope, GetOrders, sharedProperties) {
    $scope.$watch(function () {
        return sharedProperties.getId()
    }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue != oldValue) {
            $scope.item = newValue;
            $scope.Orders = GetOrders.query({ id: item });
        }
    });
});
```

Service.js

```
var app = angular.module("ServiceApp", ["ngResource"]);

    app.factory('GetPortfolios', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolios/");
    });

    app.factory('GetOrders', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/GetPortfolioOrders/");
    });

    app.factory('CreatePortfolio', function ($resource) {
        return $resource("http://localhost:61347/api/PortfolioManager/CreatePortfolio");
    });
```

Html

```
<div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="form" ng-controller="CreatePortfolioController">
                                    <form class="cmxform form-horizontal " id="signupForm" method="get" ng-submit="create(data)" action="">
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                            <label for="portfolioname" class="control-label col-lg-3">Portfolio Name</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <input class= "form-control" ng-model="data.portfolioName"  name="portfolioname" type="text" required />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                            <label for="portfoliotype" class="control-label col-lg-3">Portfolio Type</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <input class= "form-control" ng-model="data.type"  name="portfoliotype" type="text" required />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group ">
                                            <label for="portfoliodesc" class= "control-label col-lg-3">Portfolio Description</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                                <textarea class="form-control " ng-model="data.description"  name="portfoliodesc" rows="3"></textarea>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                       
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-6">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save <i class="fa fa-check"></i></button><!--Write Save code-->
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Cancel <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button><!--Write clear text box code-->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Sequence of imported files

```
<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="~/AngularScripts/PM/App.js"></script>
<script src="~/AngularScripts/PM/Service.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is your `ng-app`?

Comment: i think its the problem with some kind of factory injection

Answer (score 0):

Please check all these conditions:

1. Your `ng-app` is included before the `ng-controller` in HTML page or
   together in the same tag.
2. Check the name of controller as it is case sensitive.
3. Make sure you have loaded the JS files properly inside the HTML page. The JS file for AngularJS library, then your app files that
   contains, sequentially- JS file with ng-app set, js files that
   define services (if any), js files that define factories (if any) ,
   js files that define your controllers. Be sure you don't miss to
   include any js files and are in proper sequence.

As i do not see controller file included in the `<script>`, in the snippet you have added.

Comment: Controller file is added. App.js

Comment: Where is your serviceApp.js file? Its below App.js and inside App,js you are using serviceApp service so it should be above App.js.

Comment: I have added the sequence of files. See the question